# making a mysql query

Tags: mysql

Hey I'm trying to figure out how to get some ranked results from mysql.
I have a db table with:

id |  eid | result

`eid` is the entrant number (this project is for results from 5 judges),
the result is a value from the `[0, 100]` interval.

So, there will be 5 results for each entrant, I want to drop the highest, and the lowest results, only leaving the 3 middle ones.

I then add the 3 results together, and there's the entrant points.

At the end of the day I need to get a list of entrant number from highest result to lowest.

So far I've got this:

```
SELECT * FROM burnout_results WHERE result NOT IN( (SELECT MIN(result)
FROM burnout_results WHERE eid='1'),
(SELECT MAX(result) FROM burnout_results WHERE eid='1') ) AND eid='2' LIMIT 3
```

But this way I can only look up 1 `eid` at a time, and I have to add up the result in php, but then I can't work out how to rank it from there ...

Can this be done mostly in the mysql lookup?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: If the second highest result is the same as the highest, then it will also be excluded.  (similarly with the min)

Comment: I see, but how to exclude the top and bottom results?  Without excluding 2 of the same high or low results?

Comment: Consider providing a sqlfiddle of same, with some duplicate max and min results, highlighting that particular aspect of the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use aggregation:

`SELECT eid, SUM(result)-MIN(result)-MAX(result) AS r FROM burnout_results GROUP BY eid;`

this way, for each `eid`, you sum all reults, subtracting the highest and lowest values

Comment: I assume this will suffer the same fate as my original one? Joel says it will exclude multiple results if there are two the same (highest or lowest)

Comment: no, aggregation functions return just one element, so even if you have multiple equals result values, it will be taken just one.

Comment: Tried it, but it just seems to return a result that shows one instance of the eid for each eid (there are multiple results for each eid of cause)

Comment: Yes, it is supposed to give you tuples containing <eid, result> with eid unique and results given as sum of all results for that eid minus min and max. I maybe misunderstood your question.

Comment: I think I don't know how to get the result, because that would be fine.  But all I can get from it is the eid,   result is empty

Comment: @MattWilliamson what is your expected results exactly ?

Comment: The expected result is exactly how you put it.  to get eid and total result for each eid.
Still I seem to only get a list of the eid this way, and it's not in points order either.

Comment: AHHHH!!!  I knew it was likley because I couldn't find the variable that held the answer, so I found that r contained the SUM, Nice!
Only problem was results were not in DESC order, added ORDER BY r DESC.   Perfect!